# Having problem in laravel passport multiple authentication

Tags: laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am trying to apply multiple authentication to laravel using passport authentication passport. But its showing every time for admin authentication. I tried many times, but not able to authentication. Please help.

This is my admin class

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is auth.php file

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

This is api.php

```
Route::post('loginEmp', 'AdminController@login');
Route::post('registerEmp', 'AdminController@register');
Route::post('detailsEmp', 'AdminController@details')->middleware('auth:admin-api');
```

This is admin controller

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public $successStatus = 200;
    /**
     * login api
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(){
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
            $user = Auth::guard('admin');
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register api
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
        }
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user = Admin::create($input);
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
        return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this-> successStatus);
    }

    /**
     * details api
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function details()
    {
        $user = Auth::guard('admin-api');
        return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this-> successStatus);
    }
}
```

Error I am getting while logging in

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::createToken does
 not exist. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\MultiAuthApi\vendor\laravel\framework
\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php on line 103
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `App\Admin` model must implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface. The `App\User` model already implements this because it extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` which implements the interface.

Perhaps you would like to have your `App\Admin` model extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` as well.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for getting user info. But now there is new error for logging in. Can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I just had to add `user()` at the end of `$user = Auth::guard('admin');`
Both authentication working now fine.